# Can you list some free CRM webapps? Possibly in PHP, possibly with OpenID support

Tags: php, crm

Not much to add, the topic says it all.

- Crm
- Free
- PHP
- OpenID
- Mysql

Oh, it would be nice if it was for php5 with a decent Template support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the answers to "[Which PHP open source CRM should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98018/which-php-open-source-crm-should-i-use)"? It's the first entry under "related" - you might want to search the other questions there too to get more detail about the usability or technical problems with the varying solutions.

It seems almost all recommendations boil down to SugarCRM...

Comment: Yeah I checked both, and I wasn't too impressed by either.

Sorry if I sound snob, but...

Comment: So which of your criteria would you waive first in order to broaden the field? I guess CRM is set - which of the others could you do without?

Comment: Well, they both have a terrible UX, and the more I look around, and the more I realize I might be looking for something that just doesn't exists...